# How to get rid of the ceil function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression and I'm wondering how to get rid of the ceil function (if possible at all):

$$ answer = 2n - 4 -  \lceil \dfrac{n}{2} \rceil $$

Is there a way to get rid of it such that I end up with a simpler answer?

Comment: $n$ is a natural number?

Comment: @tilper yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lceil n/2 \rceil = n/2$ if $n$ is even, $(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd. 
 You could write that as $$\frac{2n + 1 - (-1)^n}4$$

Comment: Is there a way to be able to generate these nice formulas like the one you presented? Or is it just experience?

Comment: Consider cases...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider two cases: when $n$ is odd and when $n$ is even. Then
$$\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil = \begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2}&\text{if $n$ is even,}\\
\frac{n+1}{2}&\text{if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$